# Question on using L' Hopital's rule

Tags: limits

How to use L' Hopital's to solve the following limit

$$\lim_\limits{K\to\infty} K^s\left(1-\frac x{2r}\right)^{K-s} $$
where $s\in Z^+$ is constant. $r\in Z^+$ is constant. $0<x<1$ is constant

Comment: I can see $lim_{K\rightarrow\infty} (1-\frac x{2r})^{K-s} $ exist in terms of some e-power, but the term $K^s$ upfront tends to go to infinity with positive exponent $s$. Just wondering, is this limit supposed to exist (i.e. a textbook problem) or does this particular limit arise from some scientific experiment (equally ok though)

Comment: convert the expression to a power of e.  The exponent will have two terms dependent on K, a positive term in ln(K) and a negative constant times K.  The limit of the exponent is $-\infty $, so the expressions has a limit of zero.

Comment: I am trying to prove some theorem that this limit is some part of it, however, I dont remember much about limits. There is similar theorem to that of mine which says the limit converges to zero when r=1.

Comment: @Reza_va Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: thanks  @gimusi i didnt know about this option on the stackexchange. Your answer was very useful

Comment: @Reza_va You are welcome! Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider

$$K^s \left(1-\frac x{2r}\right)^{K-s}=e^{s\log K+(K-s)\log \left(1-\frac x{2r}\right)}\to e^{-\infty}=0$$

indeed

$$s\log K+(K-s)\log \left(1-\frac x{2r}\right)=K\cdot\left( s\frac{\log K}{K}+\frac{(K-s)}{K}\log \left(1-\frac x{2r}\right)\right)\to -\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Set
$$
1-\frac{x}{2r}=\frac{1}{y^s}
$$
and note that $y>1$. Then your limit is
$$
\lim_{K\to\infty}\left(\frac{K}{y^{K}}\right)^sy^{s^2}
$$
Prove now that
$$
\lim_{K\to\infty}\frac{K}{y^K}=0
$$
(with l'Hôpital, if you so wish, there are other methods).